# LifecycleObservable for click event in background

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I changed the [RxAndroid example](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/blob/0.x/sample-app/src/main/java/rx/android/samples/LifecycleObservableActivity.java) a little bit to execute the click task in the background but it doesn't work :-(

Here my code:

```
/**
 * Simple example of creating a Subscription that is bound to the lifecycle
 * (and thus automatically unsubscribed when the Activity is destroyed).
 */
public class LifecycleObservableActivity extends RxActivity {

    private static final String TAG = LifecycleObservableActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Button button;

    private Subscription subscription;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Click Me!");
        setContentView(button);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart();

        Observable<OnClickEvent> clicks = ViewObservable.clicks(button)
                // .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());  IllegalStateException: Observers must subscribe from the main UI thread, but was Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-3,5,main]
                .observeOn(Schedulers.computation());

        subscription =
                LifecycleObservable.bindActivityLifecycle(lifecycle(), clicks)
                        .map(x -> {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Func1   - main thread: " + isCurrentlyOnMainThread() + " (" + Thread.currentThread() + ")");
                            return "hallo welt";
                        })
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(string -> {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Action1 - main thread: " + isCurrentlyOnMainThread() + " (" + Thread.currentThread() + ")");
                            Toast.makeText(LifecycleObservableActivity.this,
                                    string,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();

        // Should output "false"
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause(), isUnsubscribed=" + subscription.isUnsubscribed());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        super.onStop();

        // Should output "true"
        Log.i(TAG, "onStop(), isUnsubscribed=" + subscription.isUnsubscribed());
    }

    private boolean isCurrentlyOnMainThread() {

        return Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper();
    }
}
```

When I run it I get this log:

```
Func1   - main thread: false (Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-3,5,main])
Action1 - main thread: true (Thread[main,5,main])
onPause(), isUnsubscribed=false
onStop(), isUnsubscribed=false
```

Func1 runs in the background that is right so far. But the subscription in not unsubscribed. It only unsubscribes when Func1 also runs in the UI thread.

What I have to change that Func1 runs in the background and the subscription will be unsubscribe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I think I got it:

```
    subscription = LifecycleObservable.bindActivityLifecycle(lifecycle(),
            AppObservable.bindActivity(this, ViewObservable.clicks(button))
                    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                    .map(new Func1<OnClickEvent, String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String call(OnClickEvent onClickEvent) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "1 " + Thread.currentThread());
                            return ((Button) onClickEvent.view()).getText().toString();
                        }
                    })
                    .map(new Func1<String, String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String call(String o) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "2 " + Thread.currentThread());
                            return "hallo " + o;
                        }
                    })
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()))
            .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
                @Override
                public void call(String s) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "3 " + Thread.currentThread());
                    Log.i(TAG, "s: " + s);
                }
            });
```

Now I bind the whole task to the Activity lifecycle and not only the `ViewObservable.clicks(button)`

With this change I got this log:

```
1 Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-3,5,main]
2 Thread[RxComputationThreadPool-3,5,main]
3 Thread[main,5,main]
s: hallo ralph
onPause subscription isUnsubscribed: false
onStop subscription isUnsubscribed: true
```